# Printing a stackpanel

Tags: wpf, printing, stackpanel

I have a WPF with content in it, and would like to print it. Using

```
PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
if (pd.ShowDialog() == true)
   pd.PrintVisual(textStack, "Chinese Pinyin Text");
```

to print however, means that if I resize my window, some stuff will get cut off. How can I print it and ensure a standard 8.5x11 piece of paper with all my content, so nothing gets cut off and it correctly flows? (IE- My window is widescreen, but when it prints, it should deliver a 8.5 by 11 paper with content correctly flowing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you create a [FlowDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.aspx) (or other XxxxDocument) from it? FlowDocuments are relatively easy to print.

Comment: Perfect! I wrapped my stack panels in `<BlockUIContainer>` and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You could create a ViewBox that wraps the StackPanel and is sized to the size you want and then print the ViewBox. That might work.

Otherwise, like Patrick said, getting your visual into a FlowDocument and having that handle paging is going to be your best bet.

Comment: I tried the ViewBox, but it seems like it gives the same effect as the StackPanel- if I resize the window, the content in the ViewBox visibly shrinks (things get skinnier but don't wrap)